# When using Google's custom search libraries with AWS Lambda, there's a NoClassDef error that does not reproduce locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-custom-search, google-client

I created a jar, added a main class and ran it using java -jar.  This executes normally, but when I upload it to AWS Lambda, I get the following:

```
{
"errorMessage": "Error loading class com.me.MyHandler:com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonResponseException",
"errorType": "class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"
}
```

Here's the log output:

```
Error loading class com.me.MyHandler: com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonResponseException: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/googleapis/json/GoogleJsonResponseException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

I unzipped the jar and found GoogleJsonResponseException.class.  Is something weird in AWS's execution environment?  Even if I don't use Google's exception, I seem to be getting errors with every Google class.

Here's the build.gradle file

```
group 'com.me'
version '1.0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-lambda-java-core', version: '1.1.0'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-lambda-java-log4j', version: '1.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'
    compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-customsearch', version: 'v1-rev54-1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-gson', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.6.2'
    runtime 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
}

mainClassName = "com.me.Main"

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

Here's the main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("starting main");
        MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
        myHandler.handleRequest(null, null);
    }
}
```

Here's the code calling Google's lib:

```
public class MyHandler implements
        RequestHandler<Map, String> {

    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyHandler.class);

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map input, Context context) {
        log.info("Handling request.");

        try {
        log.info("Initializing custom search");

        Customsearch.Builder builder = new Customsearch.Builder(
                GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(),
                null);
        builder.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new CustomsearchRequestInitializer("test"));
        builder.setApplicationName("testQuery");
        Customsearch customsearch = builder.build();
        Customsearch.Cse.List list = customsearch.cse().list("test");
            list.setKey("test");
            list.setCx("test");

            Search results;
            try {
                results = list.execute();
            } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException gjre) {
                log.error(gjre.getMessage());
                throw gjre;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
            gse.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Pack your dependencies to the jar as well.

Comment: It's packed here: configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } . Using java -jar to execute the code did not have an issue.  In addition, I unzipped the jar and found the offending class file.

Answer (score 0):

I cut a support ticket to AWS and found a way around the issue.  Looks like the fat jar step didn't fully package everything.  Instead, they suggested uploading a build zip (add this to end of gradle file):

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources              
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtime
    }           
}
```

I added that and uploaded the zip instead of the jar.  Worked just fine.